# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\look_api.php on line 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I got a script called look_api.php for a generator.

But when I try it I get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\look_api.php on line 3
```

The page:

```
<?php
                    error_reporting(1);
  $user = str_replace("'", "\\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $_GET['user']); 
                    if($username = NULL) { $username = "Yvan" };

        $con=mysqli_connect("MYSQL_IP","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
        // Mysql Connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Ai, check je mysql connection!: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {


        ?>
```

```
        <?php
         }

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

    </div> </div>
```

When I remove the ; on the line I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\xampp\htdocs\look_api.php on line 4
```

The code in the script is on that moment:

```
<?php
                    error_reporting(1);
  $user = str_replace("'", "\\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $_GET['user']) 
                    if($username = NULL) { $username = "Yvan" };

        $con=mysqli_connect("MYSQL_IP","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
        // Mysql Connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Ai, check je mysql connection!: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {


        ?>
```

```
        <?php
         }

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

    </div> </div>
```

So... How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have missed `)` in here:

```
 $user = str_replace("'", "\\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $_GET['user']);
```

should be :

```
 $user = str_replace("'", "\\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $_GET['user']));
```

you also have errors in :

```
if($username = NULL) { $username = "Yvan" };
```

should be :

```
if($username == NULL) { $username = "Yvan"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in 3rd and 4th line

3rd line you missing `)`
4th line semicolon should be inside of `if` statement

Replace it..

```
$user = str_replace("'", "\\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $_GET['user'])); 
if($username == NULL) { $username = "Yvan"; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
if($username = NULL) { $username = "Yvan" };
```

With:

```
if($username = NULL) { $username = "Yvan"; }
```

Comment: What is the negative for?That's also an error in the code.

Comment: I already got my fix :)